# Java: returning the Object from which the function was called

Tags: java, jackson

Im working with Jackson (a Java JSON library) and I have a problem, I want to use the JavaFile--> JsonString function in the same Class as the parameter of the function.
To clarify:

```
return mapper.writeValueAsString(this.Object());<----this doesnt work
}

 public static class Test {

    private String jsonStuff;
    private List<String> moreJsonStuff = new ArrayList<>();
    private String evenMoreJsonStuff;
```

I don't want to write a "JavaToJSOnParser" or something like that, because I've been told that was bad code.

Thanks

Comment: do you want to execute `writeValueAsString()` and pass an instance of your inner `Test` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is pretty unclear, but it's possible that you're just looking for:

```
return mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
```